# ajax/jQuery Youtube playlist push

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, youtube

so I currently have this PHP script to get the Youtube IDS set in a mySQL database. This PHP script lists all the Youtube ID's in the database.

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "songrequests";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM test";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "song: " . $row["link"]. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Ok, and after that, I found this script that pushes Youtube IDs to a playlist, this is found here on [jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/masiha/tFQEN/1/) (Full demo [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/masiha/tFQEN/1/show/))

So basically, what I am trying to achieve is to push the IDs from my database to the list. I created a json which lists all of the IDs [here](http://dj.aotikbot.tv/songlist.php)

With this ajax I'm trying to push the ID's from the json to the list, but it does not seem to work.

**JS**

```
       $.ajax({
            url: 'http://dj.aotikbot.tv/songlist.php',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',                                                                                                                                                                                                
        success: function(data) { 

        console.log(data.songs.length); 
        if (data.songs.length != 0) {

                for (var x = 0; x < data.songs.length; x++) {
                ytplayer_playlist.push("'" + data.songs[x].link + "'");
            }

            } 

        },                                                                                                                                                                                       
        error: function() { console.log('Uh Oh!'); },      
        });
```

If you need more info on what I'm trying to do, let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _does not seem to work_ is very broad. Can you be a bit more detail oriented?

Comment: Im basically trying to get the ID's from the json, and push them to the playlist like so   `ytplayer_playlist.push( 'SwigFQCnZQI' );`, but adding the ID from the ajax function instead. I believe the function works, but the video is not pushed to the list.

Comment: Right, what does `console.log(data)` output?

Comment: It outputs 2, which is correct, the number of ID's in the the DB

Comment: So, what you have [http://dj.aotikbot.tv/songlist.php](http://dj.aotikbot.tv/songlist.php) is a JSON string. Hence, try `$.parseJSON(data).songs[x].link`

Comment: I mean that's not really the problem, the problem is to actually push to the list. Eg, `ytplayer_playlist.push( ID from json )`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72829/discussion-between-lshetty-and-aotik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, based on our chat, JSONP is what you went after. The code below should work. Take a look.

```
var playlist = [];
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://dj.aotikbot.tv/songlist.php?callback=?',
    type: 'GET',
    async: false, //evil, but you needed this!
    dataType: 'json',                                                                                                                                                                                                
    success: function(data) { 

        if (data.songs.length > 0) {
            $.each(data.songs, function() {
               playlist.push(this.link);
            });
        }
        console.log("Here is your playlist");
        console.log(playlist);
    },                                                                                                                     
    error: function() { console.log('Uh Oh!'); }
});
```